# What does 'dynamically scalable' mean?

Tags: blockchain-size, dynamic-blocksize-limit, scalability

I heard this term being used in a monero promo video I saw on Reddit but don't know what it means. Something to do with the size of the blocks maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blocksize can automatically adjust over the course of time by the miners including more or less transactions than what has recently been the norm however they have to pay a penalty fee if they increase it by more than a certain distance from the median of recent blocks. I guess the idea is to let the market decide what the blocksize should be rather than have the kind of issues bitcoin is having right now.